# ERROR: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/13/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgis

Ubuntu 21.10 , PostgreSQL 13.

[image]

I catch error

```
ERROR: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/13/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory
```

how to fix it?

Comment: Install the extension using your package manager.  Or build it from source if you like.  It is in its own package, not installed by default.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo apt install postgis postgresql-13-postgis-3-scripts
create extension postgis;
```